# how to get drawable width and height in a 120dpi screen?

Tags: android

I want to get my drawable  Intrinsic Width and Height.

it's work good in 160 dpi screen but when i run the emulator in 120 dpi it return small valuse than 160 dpi.

so how to get the same right value as the 160 dpi screen ?

here is the code that initialize my image in Drawable object :

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);
```

thanks in advance.

Edit adding sample :

this is the correct values in 160 dpi >> height =726 width =602

this is the wrong values in 120 dpi >> height =545 width =452

how to make the 120 dpi same as 160 dpi  for Intrinsic Width and Height ?

Comment: why would you want something like that ?

Comment: i make a book reader with highligh on line so i need to get the original x and y from the image so i can highlight this line

Comment: in 160 dpi i highlight correct but in 120 dpi the highlight is wrong

Comment: Please could you explain with many more details (and maybe a schema ?) what you want to do in terms of functionalities. I think I understood what you're actually trying to do in terms of code, but I think your approach is wrong, so I think I might answer you correctly if I understand what you want =)

Comment: i have a book pages as images and every line x and y is stored in database..i want to highlight the original x and y of image on the scaled x and y while audio reach this line

Comment: Ok, and of course, your scanned pages have fixed size you already know right ? I'll write an answer in a few minutes

Comment: yes i already know it's size and it work well in 160 dpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution to get correct  Intrinsic Width and Height :

```
  Bitmap pageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mBitmapIds[index]);    
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        if (dm.densityDpi == 120) {
            pageBitmap.setDensity(90);
        } else if (dm.densityDpi == 120) {
            pageBitmap.setDensity(160);
        } else if (dm.densityDpi == 240) {
            pageBitmap.setDensity(360);
        } else if (dm.densityDpi == 320) {
            pageBitmap.setDensity(640);
        }

        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), pageBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your width is 100 use:

```
100 px
```

Instead of:

```
100 dpi
```

In this way android not apply the scaling factor of the dpi unit and the dimension is the same in any screen...

Comment: this is the correct values in 160 dpi >> height =726
width =602
this is the wrong values in 120 dpi >>
height =545
width =452
how to make the 120 dpi same as 160 dpi

Comment: i think you don't understand me well..i get drawable Intrinsic Width and Height in runtime to highlight the original x and y in book app

Comment: I don't understand why a value of height and width is wrong if the value in dip unit is different...

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

As explain in this link denisty indipendet pixel, if the dpi of the monitor change and you use width = xx dp instead of width = xx px this value is correct that change from a 160 dpi monitor and 120 dpi monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the size of your images is `width` and `length`.
I suggest you draw your pages and the highlight in a custom view, overriding `onDraw(Canvas)`, like this :

```
class PageHilghlighter extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // The Canvas you receive is automatically clipped so that its clip bounds reflect the space dedicated to your view
        Rect bounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
        Drawable myPage = getCurrentPage(); // To implement
        int saveCount = canvas.save();
        // Scale the canvas so that your page fills your view
        canvas.scale(myPage.getIntrisicWidth() / bounds.width(), myPage.getIntrisicHeight() / bounds.height());
        myPage.draw(canvas);
        float x = getLineX(); // To implement
        float y = getLineY(); // To implement
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + myLineWidth(), y + myLineHeight(), myPaint); // Use some transparent paint ...
        canvas.restore(saveCount);
    }
}
```

Something like that should work. I didn't tested it though.

Comment: i will test your code .
i am using pagr curl in opengl to show the page and a customview to show the highlight

Comment: but why is myPage.getIntrisicWidth() in 160 dpi is the same as the real width and in 120 dpi is smaller and what is the value i should multiply to get as 160 dpi

Comment: from documentation>>getIntrinsicWidth >>
 Return the intrinsic width of the underlying drawable object.

Comment: i believe your drawable is being resized to fit the container that draws it. That's why i suggest drawing it by hand in my sample code.

Comment: Yes i read this too while composing the answer. Seems strange. How do you obtain your page as a drawable in the first place ?

Comment: could you look to my solution

Comment: that will work, but its only a hack. I don't understand why you persist to work with dpis. Anyways, DisplayMetrics can help you convert dpis to px and vice versa.

Comment: i get my bitmap from drawable by this code >>                        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);

Comment: i insist to work with dpis because my code depend on Intrinsic Width and Height and the original touched x and y..in reading audio when touch the line and database working .